# Partial update of sqlite 3 table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite

I have two pandas data frame `df1` and `df2`, each of is 5 columns and 100 rows. I concatenated both data frame and now it is 10x100. I insert this data frame (`df3`) to sqlite3 table.

```
df3.to_sql(name='table', con=conn)
```

What I want is to update the df1 data frame, keeping the values of df2 part unchanged. Is there an easy way to do so

Comment: Do you want to update them in the sql table or inside python?

Comment: update inside table in db, i have a loop, where values get updated in python, and I want to update them in db, but not all of them, only few columns

Comment: Have you tried raw sql commands that update columns of df1 only? Alternatively you could update df1 in python and reconcate it with df2 and save it again to sql

Comment: i have to mention each column individually, which I don't want to do. actually, there are not 5 columns, there are 30 columns

Comment: If it's 100 rows only, you could reconcat them and save it again to db

Comment: it will replace all columns. what i am doing is fetching all data back from db, replacing the desired column and saving the database, and doing this inloop

Answer (score 0):

For such a small table you can amend df1, reconcatenate it with df2 and resave df3 to sql using `if_exists='replace'`

```
df3.to_sql(name='table', if_exists='replace', con=conn)
```